# Can dreams be memorised?

Tags: memory, dreams, brain-training

Would it be possible to activate the human memory and "access" it by means of encouraging certain hormones, to assist a sleeping body to memorize dreams and later (meaning minutes, days, months or even years) access it again with the same hormones - something like a trained body function.

This could perhaps help in solving certain criminal cases or assist in psychological healing (for schizophrenia and the likes). I'm just curious about the possibilities and have absolutely no knowledge of how the brain works. This was just a wild idea that came to mind and I was wondering about the possibilities.

Comment: This is a bit too "science fiction" at this point.  I'd recommend poking through some of the upvoted questions within the `dreams` tag to familiarize yourself with some of the actual physiology first.

Comment: There's quite a bit of good information on [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep) as well.

Comment: I think this can be easily answered. I will find my course notes one of these days to give the details, but it is known that some neurotransmitter necessary for translating short-term into long-term menory is inactive during sleep.

Comment: @Ana The question in the title can be easily addressed, depending on how one defines "memorized", but the remainder of the question is just idle speculation.

Comment: Yes, dreams can be memorized, (but there are persons that don't remember their dreams), although they continue to be just dreams, not reality. Therefore how would they help to solve criminal cases, which are from real world?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's inputs! @Di Ana I working on hear-say here, but I've heard and experienced that, even though dreams are just garble, they do contain bits and pieces of events that occurred. Especially after a horrible experience or the like. String those bits together and there's your key to unlock

Comment: Dreams don't contain bits of reality exactly as it have occurred. They contain images of everyday's life and events, but colored by the subject's emotions, pictured through the personal, idiosyncratic way he sees them. It is not possible to say that reality has happened the same way it appears in dreams. See it by yourself. Even the most realistic dream contains distortions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it is when it goes about hormones but for sure dreams can be remembered and this remembering of dreams can be improved.

One of the most popular methods is trying to think about somebody's dreams just after waking up. It is also important to tell it loudly, record it or write it down.
After some time (even few days) of writing down your dreams a person is able to remember not one, but two, three or more dreams from one night.

The case of getting access to your previous dreams lately is connected with lucid dreaming - if you are able to have lucid dreams whenever you want, you also can initiate these situations which you like. But it is much less scientifically described case.